# Verbatim code in scaladoc

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I have a Color companion object which holds a few useful colors, and I'd like to
document them in the following manner:

```
object Color {
  /** (.3, .3, .3, 1) */
  val darkGrey = Color(.3, .3, .3, 1);
}
```

As you have probably noticed, all I want is for the string `(.3, .3, .3, 1)` to
show up right below `val darkGrey` in the documentation for `Color`. The problem is that
Scaladoc takes everything before the first period to be a sentence, and
everything after that before is hidden "inside" the expandable arrow. So what I
get is something like this:

[image]

which is clearly undesirable. Ideally, either the entire string would be shown
or the entire string would be hidden. Is there a way to achieve either of these?

I've also tried the two following methods, and none of them work.

```
object Color {
  /**
    * (.3, .3, .3, 1)
    */
  val darkGrey = Color(.3, .3, .3, 1);
}
object Color {
  /** {{{
    * (.3, .3, .3, 1)
    * }}}
    */
  val darkGrey = Color(.3, .3, .3, 1);
}   
object Color {
  /** ` (.3, .3, .3, 1) ` */
  val darkGrey = Color(.3, .3, .3, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the period detection is in a late stage of scaladoc, it doesn't matter how it's generated or escaped. The only solution I found is a bit wacky -- you need to avoid the period. Use a different unicode:

```
/** @define dot \u2024 */
object Color {
  /** `(${dot}3, ${dot}3, ${dot}3, 1)` */
  val darkGrey = Color(.3, .3, .3, 1);
}
case class Color(r:Double,g:Double,b:Double,alpha:Double)
```

If you save your source code in UTF-8, I guess you can also directly paste the alternative period character.